eas submit - The app name you entered is already being used for another app
So ive been working on this app for over a year. Ive done many updates to this app. Today when i tried to submit a new version of the app i received this error
"
The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used on this account. - The app name you entered is already being used for another app in your account. If you would like to use the name for this app you will need to submit an update to your other app to change the name, or remove it from App Store Connect.
Visit https://appstoreconnect.apple.com and resolve any warnings, then try again.
Submission failed
"
What in the world do i do lol
